# Kotlin annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant

Tags: android, kotlin

```
@BindView(R.id.et_login_username)
internal var loginUsername: EditText? = null
```

> Kotlin annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant

This is the error that's showing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To use `ButterKnife` in `Kotlin`, make sure you have added the following dependencies in **app gradle**.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:latest-version'

    // use kapt for kotlin
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:latest-version'
}
```

In your activity, declare views using `lateinit` to avoid *compile-time constant error*:

```
@BindView(R.id.et_login_username)
lateinit var loginUsername: EditText
```

---

Moreover, Kotlin developers also introduced an alternative for binding android views which eliminates `findViewById` calls. Its known as [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html),

To use this:

In **app's** `build.gradle`, add this plugin

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

In Activity,

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       // All views can be used directly with their id declared in the xml
       et_login_username.setText("Hello")
}
```

Comment: et_login_username.text="hello"i tried this but ti says(Type Mismatch)--> Required editable.. But found String

Comment: I've updated my answer. `et.text` expects an `Editable` not `String`, so I changed it to `et.setText`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and presents an entire different solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @zsmb13 I have updated the answer. I think now it answers the problem in a proper way.

Comment: Sure does: you need to make your view `lateinit`