# An Annotation argument must be a compile time constant

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

i have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49422901/kotlin-annotation-parameter-must-be-a-compile-time-constant) question. Similar error.But in my case it is different.

While working with Room i was creating table. it was working fine.

```
@Daointerface 
UserDao {
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
fun getAll(): List<User>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(user: User)

@Delete
fun delete(user: User)}
```

but then i found all table Names must be stored in a different class. like table name "user" - > Stored in different class.

Eg.

```
class Table {
companion object {
    const val USER_TABLE = "user"
}}
```

But below code is not working . **it is not picking up table name from Table class. Giving compile time error** . "An Annotation argument must be a compile time constant" please help me out.What wrong in it

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM $Table.USER_TABLE")
fun getAll(): List<User>
```

Comment: Why negative marking, i didn't understand. Whats illogical in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the one stated in the error, you can't have dynamically defined arguments for your `@Query` annotation. If you want to define the name of the table somewhere else, use string concatenation. You can do it like this:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " + Table.USER_TABLE)
fun getAll(): List<User>
```

This is how they do it in this [google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/PersistenceContentProviderSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/contentprovidersample/data/CheeseDao.java) sample.

Comment: But in koltin , String concatenation is done using "$ symbol". when i convert your concat string into kotlin code . it showed me like this . @Query("""SELECT * FROM ${Table.USER_TABLE}""")

Comment: I've been doing with the + sign and it's been working. https://github.com/Levi-Moreira/TeamManagerApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/levimoreira/teammenagerapp/person/data/PersonDao.kt My guess is that the kotlin interpolation is evaluated at runtime and it might not work properly with annotation arguments that need to be evaluated at compile time.

Answer (score 18):

You need to escape the String concatenation when using `@Value` annotation with the dollar symbol in Kotlin (prepend `\` to `$`):

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM \$Table.USER_TABLE")
fun getAll(): List<User>
```

Comment: This escapes the $-sign and leads to no string substitution at all. What do you mean with "@Value annotation" ???

Answer (score 3):

You should define column name also in data class and access if you want to use columns in queries and access it via this method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${Table.USER_TABLE}")
```

Comment: this ends up in the same issue