# Using java Custom Annotation in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations

I've created a custom annotation in java and I'm trying to use it in a Kotlin written class but in the compile time, I'm getting an error:

> Annotation parameter must be a compile-time constant

Here is the code:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface EdsFieldInfo {
  int persianName();
  String columnName() default "";
  int domainVals() default -1;
}
```

This is the place where I'm using the annotation

```
@EdsFieldInfo(persianName = R.string.customer_file_id, columnName = "FileId")
@ColumnInfo(name = "FileId", typeAffinity = ColumnInfo.TEXT)
var fileId: String?,
```

and the error is shown here

```
persianName = R.string.customer_file_id
```

I try to find a solution for this but couldn't please help me to resolve this matter? Thank you.

Comment: Problem is in the first line & second : `persianName = R.string.customer_file_id, culomnName = "FileId"` Mostly the suspect: `persianName = R.string.customer_file_id` -  `culomnName = "FileId"` & `name = "FileId"` Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50679302/4409113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `R` is compiled during compile-time, I would highly suspect you cannot use such `R.string.customer_file_id` variable in an annotation. Maybe it gets evoluated before Android's builder actually builds `R`.

So I'm afraid you should use a constant instead.

Comment: that's correct but I'm wondering how is was working in main project and it started throwing this error  after I moved my code to a library project

Comment: Maybe your `R.string.customer_file_id` is still in your main project? If you moved your code to another module it need to be inside that module I believe.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure which I moved related strings too