# How to set Retrofit URL string from Resources

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I've refactored some parts of my code which is written in Kotlin and tend to put url's in strings.xml, but when I want to point to the string in strings.xml file in annotation part of the Retrofit, I get the following error.

> An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

Here is my code:

```
interface SampleApiService {
    @GET(Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.sample_url))
    fun getSamples(){
    }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong?

Found the answer in the following post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An Annotation argument must be a compile time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678667/an-annotation-argument-must-be-a-compile-time-constant)

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32559579/3050249

Comment: @Miha_x64 tnx to you, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As documentation states it compiles your application resources at build time. and Annotation processing takes place at compile time. So you see you cannot pass resources string to a annotation

> The Android SDK tools compile your application's resources into the
>   application binary at build time.

instead create static string variable and pass it in annotation

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the example provided - one could as well just use a static URL. It would need to be annotated alike this, in order not to use any run-time values and be able to change it at run-time:

```
@GET("{path}")
fun getSamples(@Path("path") path: String) {}
```

Then one can load whatever `String path` from string resources, at run-time. When the base URL shall be changed, one may need to reconfigure the client. That is because this `interface` definition is being used by the annotation processor to generate the abstraction layer from it - at compile time already, not at run-time... when taking the complaint literal, it would have to look alike this:

```
@GET(Constants.SOME_PATH)
fun getSamples() {}
```

but there is little advance over just hard-coding that `String`, because it cannot be changed later.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,
Tnx to [Retrofit 2 - Dynamic URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559333/retrofit-2-dynamic-url/32559579#32559579)

I had to use another annotation mark of retrofit.

> New: @Url parameter annotation allows passing a complete URL for an endpoint.

Here is the result:

```
interface SampleApiService {
    @GET
    fun getSamples(
        @Url url: String =
            Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.sample_url)
    )
            : Deferred<ArrayList<Sample>>

}
```