# Issue in query parameters:An Annotation argument must be a compile time constant

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to set room query parameters by Enum:

```
enum class Status(val status:Int){
    NOTANSWERED(1),
    ANSWERED(2),
    WRONGANSWERED(3)
}
```

the query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM questions where status=${Status.NOTANSWERED.status}")
    suspend fun getNotAnsweredQuestions()
```

IDE get error:

```
An Annotation argument must be a compile time constant
```

I have also read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50678667/an-annotation-argument-must-be-a-compile-time-constant) but not solved my issue

Comment: Show me your db converter for the enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this recent issuetracker discussion; like the IDE error says, your value is not a compile time constant; using an enum value or an enum value property directly in a query annotation is not possible: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170235802

The final comment #5 (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170235802#comment5) suggests a fairly straightforward workaround: create another function that passes the value:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM questions where status=:status")
protected suspend fun getQuestions(status: Int)

suspend fun getNotAnsweredQuestions() = getQuestions(Status.NOTANSWERED.status)
```

In addition I recommend using a `@TypeConverter`, so that you can pass your enum values directly (`Status.NOTANSWERED`) instead of their properties (`Status.NOTANSWERED.status`).